# How to create polygons to display running number in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to create a node that is simply a rectangle with a number in it. And this is how I'm doing it now:

```
int size = 100, fontSize = 64;
auto node = DrawNode::create();
Vec2 vertices[] =
{
    Vec2(0,size),
    Vec2(size,size),
    Vec2(size,0),
    Vec2(0,0)
};
node->drawPolygon(vertices, 4, Color4F(1.0f,0.3f,0.3f,1), 0, Color4F(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1));
auto texture = new Texture2D();
int numberToDisplay = 2000;
std::string s = std::to_string(numberToDisplay);
texture -> initWithString(s.c_str(), "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", fontSize, Size(size, size), TextHAlignment::CENTER, TextVAlignment::CENTER);
auto textSprite = Sprite::createWithTexture(texture);
node -> addChild(textSprite);
textSprite -> setPosition(size/2, size/2);
```

Every time I want to change the number I have to re-create a textureSprite, remove the current child and add the new one. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wonder whether you want some special features, so why not use LayerColor and labelTTF?

```
LayerColor* node = LayerColor::create(Color4B(255, 85, 85, 255), 100, 100);
LabelTTF* label = LabelTTF::create(s, "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", fontSize);
node->addChild(label);
```

just change content of labelttf,no need to create sprite

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves the problem of displaying running numbers because I can just call label.setString() to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different techniques for achieve this, to me both of them are good

1:- Use texture cache to cache texture and change image texture at run time(good if u know how many exact textures are there and texture has same Size). in your .h file define no of textures like:-

```
   Texture2D *startTexture, *endTexture, *midTexture;
```

in you .cpp file do it like:-

```
   startTexture = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage(
        "start.png");
   endTexture = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage(
        "end.png");
   middleTexture = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage(
        "middle.png");
```

after that when you want to change texture of any Sprite, simply do it like:-

```
         textSprite->setTexture(startTexture);
```

for this to work with you, declare "textSprite" in your .h file aswell for quick access.

Pit-fall:- changing texture doesn't change sprite initial bounding box, if initial sprite texture was 32*32 and changed texture was 50*50, then extra texture of 20*20 will be cropped automatically starting from origin point, which might look bad. to over come this you need to change rect also using

```
    textSprite->setTextureRect(
                Rect(0, 0, startTexture->getContentSize().width,
                        startTexture->getContentSize().height));
```

2:- Using Sprite Frame Cache, put all your texture in a spriteframe, load it into memory like :-

```
    SpriteFrameCache *spriteCache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
    spriteCache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("test.plist", "test.png");
```

now when ever you want to change you texture do it like this

```
    testSprite->setSpriteFrame(
                    (SpriteFrameCache::getInstance())->getSpriteFrameByName(
                            "newImage.png"));
```

this will first check sprite cache for a image named "newImage.png", if it found it in memory then it will return that texture or else it will return nullptr.